# When to use ngOnChanges vs Pipes

Tags: angular

So far on my Angular journey, I have not had a great deal of need for pipes.

A common theme so far is that most components have an `@Input` of some data coming in, which may need some operating on before being used by the template.

This leaves a rather dirty situation:

```
// data coming in
@Input data: MyDataInterface;

// data after massage, it is this which powers the template
config: MyDataInterfaceAfterMassage;

// the masseuse works in here and creates a new "config" object
ngOnChanges() {

}
```

But then it occurred to me, I guess I could also do this with Pipes but not sure on where the distinction is made.

Given the choice between `ngOnChanges` and `Pipe`, under what circumstance would you use one over the other when relative to binding to the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast and easy : `ngOnChanges` is used to detect a change from a variable decorated with `@Input`, and pipes are used to display data that are displayed in a particular format, but their value isn't changed.

Comment: Thank you! Fast and Easy statements like this is always preferred!